# Change a Date String to Datetime format Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert string Datetime in a dataframe to datetime, but i am get the error `ValueError: time data DATETIME doesn't match format specified`.

```
print(chunk['DATETIME']) gives this

0               DATETIME
1    2019-12-25 15:46:42
2    2019-12-25 15:46:43
3    2019-12-25 15:47:39
4    2019-12-25 15:47:42
Name: DATETIME, dtype: object
```

This is what i have done.

```
chunk['DATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(chunk['DATETIME'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(chunk['DATETIME'])
```

And that gives me error. I have tried to remove empty spaces that might be there

```
chunk['DATETIME'] = chunk['DATETIME'].str.strip()
print(chunk['DATETIME'])
```

But i still get the same error. Your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: just `pd.to_datetime(df['DATETIME'])` works for the input

Comment: Please i don't understand your comment.  If you meant when i was creating the dataframe, The Dataframe is coming from a csv file

Comment: Apologies for not being clear, I meant you can either let pandas parse the format `pd.to_datetime(df['DATETIME'])`  or do `pd.to_datetime(df['DATETIME'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` where `%` is missing from your code for formatting the minute

Comment: Sorry, i missed the sign, but it is actually part of my code. Here is the error i get. `ValueError: time data DATETIME doesn't match format specified` Let me update the question appropriately

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it seemed to work for me. Can you provide more information on your data? Or perhaps try to restart your kernel?

```
import pandas as pd
chunk = pd.DataFrame({"DATETIME":['2019-12-25 15:46:42','2019-12-25 15:46:43']})
chunk["DATETIME"] = pd.to_datetime(chunk["DATETIME"], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(chunk['DATETIME'])
chunk.info()
```

**Output**

```
0   2019-12-25 15:46:42
1   2019-12-25 15:46:43
Name: DATETIME, dtype: datetime64[ns]
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------    --------------  -----         
 0   DATETIME  2 non-null      datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1)
memory usage: 144.0 bytes
```